# C++ Multithreading methods in an object with infinite loops

Tags: c++, multithreading

I never did any C++ or multithreading before and need help about something.

Let's suppose I have this in my hpp file.

```
Class Test{
  public:
  struct type_something_to_kill_the_foo_thread something_to_kill_the_foo_thread;// I don't know what
  void foo(stuff stuff){
    while(true) does_stuff(stuff);
  }
  void thread_foo(stuff stuff){
  std::thread th = (&Test::foo, this, stuff);
  something_to_kill_the_foo_thread = th; // or th.getid() any mechanism so that I can invoke a function to destroy the thread
  sleep(MAX_INT);
  }
}
```

And I have this in my main.

```
Test t = Test();
t.thread_foo("random stuff1");
t.thread_foo("random stuff2");
...
```

How can I parallelize these two calls without using a thread in my main so my main keeps going ? Where do I put my join() if I need one and how to destroy the first thread ?

I have been having a hard time with online tutorials as they always call std::thread in the main().

Comment: There's a lot of examples, even on cppreference.com. Return std::thread from thread_foo and call std::thread::join() in the end.

Comment: To kill the thread you probably want a `std::atomic_flag`. The thread periodically checks the flag and exits if it is set. Another thread sets the flag (and maybe `join`s). You **DO NOT** want to terminate a running thread. It can destabilize the whole program. The C++ Standard left a thread-killing method out for very good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you make a thread:

```cpp
#include <thread>

int main() {
  Test t = Test();

  std::thread(t.thread_foo, "random stuff1").detach()
  std::thread(t.thread_foo, "random stuff2").detach()
  // Works in parallel
}
```